# Why does JQuery's addClass method work in localhost, but not on a live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code is part of the live chat system of the application. Here is what i am trying to do.

Please refer this screenshot for better understanding : https://nimb.ws/IcoP34

In this pop up modal there is left sidebar where we are able to search the users.

Based on input in search box, code is fetching users from database and replacing the div with searched user list ( whole html content of div ) is coming through ajax.

Once user click on any user on searched result, it should say active or say active class should be added to that  li.

Code is working fine in localhost but not working in live server.

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_user_id', function(){

        $('ul.user_list > li.active').removeClass('active');        
        $(this).addClass('active');        
        var recipient_idd = $(this).data('list_user_id');

        $('#recipient_idd').val(recipient_idd);

        $('.message_box_footer').show(100);

        $.ajax({
          url: "<url>"+$(this).data('list_user_id'),
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data){
            $('.direct-chat-messages').html(data);
            $('#direct-chat-messages').animate({scrollTop: $('#direct-chat-messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
            $('#list_user_id_'+recipient_idd).addClass('active');  
            console.log('added active class in success message');

            $('#message_count_'+recipient_idd).text('0');
            $('#message_count_'+recipient_idd).hide();

          }
        });  
    });
```

In desktop, it's working fine: https://nimb.ws/9qAM2i
In live server, facing the issue: https://nimb.ws/fa9G2h

In the live server, active class is not added to the user's li tag.

Here is my html code :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked user_list" style="width: 100%; min-height: 200px; height: auto; overflow-y: auto !important;">
          <?php 
            // $users = $this->ion_auth->users()->result();
            foreach ($users as $row) {
              if($row->id != $this->session->userdata('userId')){
          ?>
          <li data-list_user_id="<?=$row->id?>" class="list_user_id" id="list_user_id_<?=$row->id?>">
            <a href="#" >
              <?php 
                if($row->profile == '' || $row->profile == null)
                {
              ?>
              <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/').'no-image.png'?>" class="user-image" height="50px" width="50px" style="border: 2px solid rgba(211,211,211,40.8);border-radius: 50px;">
              <?php 
                }
                else
                {
              ?>
              <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/<?php echo $row->profile;?>" class="user-image" height="50px" width="50px" style="border: 2px solid rgba(211,211,211,40.8);border-radius: 50px;">
              <?php
                }
              ?>
              <?=ucwords($row->first_name." ".$row->last_name)?>
              <?php 
                $message_count = $this->messages_model->get_unread_message_by_user($row->id);
                // if(sizeof($message_count) > 0)
                // {

              ?>  
              <span style="font-weight: bold; position: absolute;right: 10px; top: 23px;border-radius: 60%;color:white;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;font-size: 13px;background-color: #8C0CE8; display :<?php if(sizeof($message_count) > 0 ) echo 'block'; else echo 'none'; ?>" class="label bg-violet text-center" id="message_count_<?=$row->id?>">
                                  <?=sizeof($message_count)?>
              </span>
              <!-- <span class="label label-primary pull-right message_count" id=""> -->
                <?php 
                  // echo sizeof($message_count);
                ?>
              <!-- </span> -->
              <?php 
                // }
              ?>
            </a>
          </li>
          <?php
              }
            }
          ?>
        </ul>
```

**LATEST PROBLEM FOUND**

1. I am searching in text box
2. Search result is clicked on li
3. Once you click on any item, ul is being reset in between we lost the li on which we need to add class active.

**SEARCH CODE**

```
$( '#user_search_term' ).keyup( function() {
        var matches = $( 'ul.user_list' ).find( 'li:contains('+ $( this ).val() +') ' );
        $( 'li', 'ul.user_list' ).not( matches ).slideUp();
        matches.slideDown();    
    });
```

Comment: My first guess: You could try opening up the developer console of your browser and looking in the network tab, if and when the ajax call is done.

Comment: I did but no unknown ajax call is being made.

Comment: Then i'm at a loss. Your code looks good to me. Only thing i can think of is, that ``recipient_idd`` is empty or not the expected value for some reason. I would just ``console.log()`` debug at this point.

Comment: checked that also. it's there.

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea then. Good luck :)

Comment: I am stucked with this since 4 days. but no clue. seems like i need to change the problem and go with other solution.

Comment: It's really weird to me, why it would work locally but not on a server. I can only think it has something to do with the ajax. But what exactly... ?

Comment: also checked .. data coming without no issue.

Comment: Are you loading the same version of jQuery in both environments? Is it possible your production env is loading more than one version of jQuery? Both of those could cause weirdness (not necessarily that, just ...well weirdness).

Comment: checking in the code

Comment: Without seeing the html we can only guess. My guesses are are the `.list_user_id` element is missing, or JQuery is not loaded properly. Check the console for errors.

Comment: I have added html code now @EternalHour

Comment: @DelightedD0D yes 2 jquery js file was included but it was of same version.

Comment: @DelightedD0D jquery is not creating any issue.

Comment: You have the element that is bound to your click event inside `$row->id != $this->session->userdata('userId')`, are you sure that condition is being met and `<li data-list_user_id="<?=$row->id?>" class="list_user_id" id="list_user_id_<?=$row->id?>">` is being created? Do you have your jquery inside a `$(document).ready(function()`? You can try moving your javascript to the bottom of `<body>`. Also, I wouldn't recommend using `document` for event delegation, you should use something closer to the element.

Comment: checked all. 1. Yes condition is being met. 2. li with specific argument is being created. 3. yes it's inside the ready function.

Comment: I have updated question with new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code which worked for me.

Problem was that `ul` was recreated every time I clicked on any search result, which was causing the issue.

So I have stored list of users in variable and replaced it once I receive a success ajax call and then add active class.

now it's working fine.

```javascript
$(document).on('click', '.list_user_id', function(){

    var old_user_list ;

    var recipient_idd = $(this).data('list_user_id');
    $('ul.user_list > li.active').removeClass('active');        
    $('ul.user_list > li').css('display','block');        
    old_user_list = $('ul.user_list').html();
    $('#recipient_idd').val(recipient_idd);
    $('.message_box_footer').show(100);

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('messages/get_single_user_messages/')?>"+$(this).data('list_user_id'),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            $('.direct-chat-messages').html(data);
            $('#direct-chat-messages').animate({scrollTop: $('#direct-chat-messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);

            $('ul.user_list').html(old_user_list);
            $('ul.user_list').find('#list_user_id_'+recipient_idd).addClass('active');
        }    
    });  
});
```

Comment: Glad this worked. You can mark this as the answer to your question with the checkbox [✓] beside this answer.

Comment: @UdoE. I will be able to do it by tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If it works correctly in the local host and not working in server so please try to remove the browser cache or open website in incognito tab.

Also please try to open both ( local and remote ) in incognito tab, and select same user, I can see you have selected different users.

If the behaviour is the same in both and you have an issue with selecting specific user, please let me know.

Comment: no there is no issue with specific user. I have tested

Comment: Please write the code which you used to show and hide users

Comment: Also try to add this line inside timeout `$('#list_user_id_'+recipient_idd).addClass('active')`

Answer (score 0):

The data transfer latency in `localhost` will be significantly lower than that of a live server. There is a higher probability that `document` isn't ready before you attach the `click` handler when you are on a live server than when you are on `localhost`.

Include your code inside the ready state change handler of `document` like this

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.list_user_id', function() {
        // ...your code
    });
});
```

Comment: @elysiancode,  was the first problem solved? If it was, then you should select an answer that solved  the problem or post an answer  yourself. If you encounter new problems, you should ask another question to capture the new problems specifically. There is no limit to the number of questions you can ask on stack overflow.

Comment: no problem is not solved. but while using ajax in search, same issue was being generated.  once you click on search result, ul list was recreated, that's what problem actually.